# Is it possible to connect 3 rear drive Tesla motors on a single axle using their differential's?

Tags: automotive-engineering, electric-vehicles

[image: this is my setup attaching 3 Tesla motors and their inverters to my main axle]

Each Tesla motor that is sold comes attached with an inverter, open differential and a gear reduction.

The image on the right of my drawing shows more clearly my preferred most recent setup with a decoupler attached to an axle to power a single waterjet as I am designing a hybrid amphibious car.

Is it possible to connect 3 Tesla motors like this by using the two differentials shown in the image? And if so how could I do that?

I assume even if all the motors spin at different rpm’s or torques that they could all equally contribute power efficiently by using these differentials on the main axle.

[image: a Tesla rear motor setup with reduction gearing, inverter, and differential connecting axles on two sides]

Comment: `is it possible to do ...?` questions almost always have a `yes` answer ... a more useful question is `how to do ...?`

Comment: How could I go about connecting these different motors to an axle?

Comment: @EmmanuelMoreno By locking both ends of each differential. The it just becomes a gearbox. Then you can run that through another differential if you wish

Comment: Use each motor to drive a hydraulic pump. then the output can be used or put the pumps in series - if the pressure ratings work.

Comment: @jsotola - or... ```Why...```